# Log of a sum with three terms

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

From other posts on here I learned that the following is true:

$$
\log(a + b) = \log\left(a \cdot \left(1 +  \frac{b}{a}\right)\right) = \log(a) + \log\left(1 +  \frac{b}{a}\right)
$$

What about $\log(a + b + c)$?

Comment: $log(a+b+c)=log((a+b)+c)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\log((a+b)+c)=\log\left((a+b)\cdot\left(1+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)\right)$$
$$=\log(a)+ \log\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)+\log\left(1+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sorry? I can't get you.

Comment: It was a + originally, idk why it was edit. @ClaudeLeibovici